# Uninitialized Constant Admin on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a fresh app with only a few gems.  Devise being one of them of course.  And when I make an Admin model via Devise's Option 1 give [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role)

... and upload to heroku, I am unable to run a db:migrate due to the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   uninitialized constant Admin
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in`each'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:256:in`get'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in`modules'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in`default_used_route'

etc...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ran `rails g devise:install` or `rails g devise install`?

Comment: Yes, everything works locally, and I've run rails g devise:install.

Comment: This is a bit silly, but did you commit your admin.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

Created another fresh rails app and everything is working now.  I believe the problem might have been that I created my Admin model with a capital "A" and some code was looking for an admin model with a lowercase "a"